# extended inline assembly: same variable for input and output

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I decided to start learning some inline assembly however I am left with a simple question for which I am unable to find a clear answer.

Take the following simple example which I found in a tutorial which performs a simple addition as such:

```
int one,two,out;

one = 1;
two = 2;

__asm__ ( "add eax, ebx;" : "=a" (out) : "a" (one) , "b" (two) );
```

Note that for the sake of my own sanity after working with intel syntax for a while, I configured GCC to use intel syntax instead of AT&T.

Now suppose I would want to leave out the "out" variable and just store the output in "one" instead (or "two" for all that matters).

How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
__asm__ ( "add eax, ebx;" 
            : "+a" (one) 
            : "b" (two) );
```

The `"+"` modifier indicates a 'read/write' operand (and must be used in the output constraint).

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
 __asm__ __volatile__(" add %0, %2": "=r" (one): "0"(one), "r" (two) )
```

By using "=r" and "r", you don't unnecessarily force the compiler to use a particular register, which helps register allocation. "0" means "use same as (output) argument 0".

Edit3: The `two` argument is in `%2`, not in `%1`, which is just a second copy of `one` (same register as `%0`). Also fixed double `%` when single should be used.

Edit2: I also added `__volatile__` to ensure that the compiler doesn't move or omit the assembler code, which can happen if the compiler does not think your code does anything useful [typically because it produces no output that the compiler uses later on]. With `__volatile__` the compiler is guaranteed to NOT move or remove the assembler code.

Edit1: Fix up syntax.

Comment: Using this example, this seems to add the variable "two" to itself giving me a result of 4 instead of the expected result which would be 3. It also does this if I use "=a" for the "one" variable and "b" for the "two" variable

Comment: Yes, I'm being daft. Too early start this morning, and it now being half past midnight is my excuse, and I'm sticking to it... ;) See edited text above.